# Object state after move semantics

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

I want to understand move semantics and rvalue reference and the object state after the function call.

For example: I expect that caller fills the list and gets to the constructor argument:

```
typedef std::list<int> IntList;
class IntHolder {
public:
  explicit IntHolder(IntList&& l)
    : m_h(l)
  {}
private:
  IntList m_h; 
};

IntList a;
a.push_back(1);
IntHolder holder(a);
// ... is 'a' guaranteed empty (not empty) here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is guaranteed to not be empty, because it was never passed as an rvalue reference: it is a declared variable, not a compiler generated temporary, and hence cannot be passed as an rvalue reference.

What's happening here is that a temporary `IntList` gets copy-constructed from `a`, and that temporary is passed to your constructor. `a` itself remains intact.

To make things really complicated: even that temporary is not moved! When you use an rvalue reference, it decays to a normal reference, which happens when you say `m_h(l)` in your initializer list. If it were otherwise, you would not be able to access `l` from within your constructor. So, the temporary is copied a second time. You can enforce move semantics by replacing `m_h(l)` with `m_h(std::move(l))`.

Whenever you try to invoke move semantics, what happens depends on how the class you are using is written. Thus, there are no language guarantees. The only thing a move constructor needs to make sure is that the destructor will not mess up when it is run. It is simply an error to access an object in any way after invoking move semantics on it.

Comment: Yes I miss the std::move() in constructor. In this case is 'a' invalid after the holder is constructed?

Comment: My misunderstand is from using of the old gcc version (gcc-4.4). In case of std::move in constructor this snippet is compiled successfully 'a' is become empty (size() == 0), when I've tried to use gcc 4.7 I got the compilation error when passing 'a' as rvalue to ctor (so I have to use std::move to create 'holder').

Comment: Well, if `a` is empty after `IntHolder holder(a)`, then that's a compiler bug, move semantics are a new feature after all. Move semantics should only apply if you used `IntHolder holder(std::move(a))`.